# Python: How to find index of a specific element in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given that, i have the below array:

```
 import numpy as np

 dt = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,2,1,3])
```

I can select the cells which has the value less than 3 by below code:

```
print(dt[dt<3])
```

**But, how may i obtain the index of the selected cells?**

my favorit result is:

```
[0,1,5,6]
```

Comment: If you want to use numpy, you could just do `np.arange(len(dt))[dt<3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,2,1,3])
np.where(x<3)
```

output:

```
(array([0, 1, 5, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

you will get all index which are true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need `numpy` for this.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v < 3]
```

Comment: is there any easier way? 
i try to avoide loops

Comment: @Jeff, there's no way to avoid loops when you need to iterate over list. Also I want to mention that this is list comprehension, not a standard loop (but still loop).

Comment: I think what Jeff meant is a loop in Python. With numpy, the loop is in C, so it's much faster

Comment: @Nakor, how much faster? 0.001% faster? If you're so sick to do optimization on loops, then just try to measure how much time it takes to initialize numpy.

Comment: I did actually. With a list of size 1M, your solution was 222ms, numpy was 8ms. So the answer is: 2700% faster in this case. And initialiation doesnt count depending on what you're working on. His post was maybe just an example for his true problem